# Webpack Loader: How to emit a single file after loader has run for every file?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin, webpack-loader

Working on a Webpack loader that needs to transform source for each file and also emit a single file based on data from all those files.  Looking at the webpack docs I wasn't quite sure if a loader can / should handle something like this or if a webpack plugin would be better suited for my use case.

I see `this.emitFile` in the api docs for webpack loaders so I was thinking that I could collect data from each file in the `this.data` object during the pitch phase of the loader and emitFile on the final pitch.  This feels like kind of a hack tho.

Is there a better way to do this with webpack loaders or should I be creating a webpack plugin instead?